# Why does digitally signing PDF with iTextSharp increases file size for 9MB

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

Can anyone tell me why PDF file size increases for 9MB when I sign it with digital signature with iTextSharp library. This is the part of code I use to sign the document.

```
MakeSignature.SignDetached(appearance, externalSignature,
                    chain, crlList, null, null, 0, CryptoStandard.CADES);
```

How to prevent from this?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of before and after? Maybe just sign a simple test PDF.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/frygs05prfyro2m/AACG7qQtvgVGWTPSAgHw0hbPa?dl=0
Here are two pdf files

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of things wrong with the way you have signed your PDF document.

At first sight, it looks as if `chain` only contains a single certificate. It should contain the complete chain, but it only contains your signing certificate ([EMAIL] ...), whereas it should contain the certificate of the issuer (eID EMAIL Issuing CA) and probably some other issuers up until a root certificate, but that's not the reason why the PDF grows to an enormous file size.

Please take a look at this screen shot:

[image]

The signature is huge because you are embedding a huge CRL. A good Certificate Authority aka CA (e.g. GlobalSign) will take precautions to make sure that the size of the Certificate Revocation List is limited in length. A good CA will create intermediary certificates and limit the number of certificates that are issued by each intermediary certificate. A good CA will also remove all certificates that are expired from the CRL.

I have downloaded the CRL you are using by using this URL:

http://ocsp.mpb-ks.org:8080/crls/search.cgi?alias=email

This is the result:

[image]

It's a file of 4752 KB. This file is stored in your PDF as a hexadecimal string, which means the URL takes about 9504 KB.

If you are confronted with a CA who creates huge CRLs (as is the case with the Ministry of Internal Affairs of the Republic of Kosovo), you shouldn't use CRL: you should use OCSP instead. The length of an OCSP response is predicatable. Instead of the full list, you get the result of a lookup in the CRL. Embedding such an OCSP response will consume less space than embedding the full CRL.

You should ask your authorities how to get the OCSP response from their services. I tried to read http://www.mpb-ks.org/eID/policies/eID_RKS_CPS.pdf but instead of a PDF, it gives me an ordinary web page in a language I don't understand. When I click on "English", it doesn't give me the translation in English. The page seems broken: many images are missing.

I see that the Key Usage allows digital signing, but I don't know if your country allows to use that key for signing PDFs. I mean: technically it is possible, but I've read a notice that says "E-Mail Signature Certificate". I assume that the certificate is meant to sign e-mail and you are using it for a different purpose. Please check with your authorities if the signatures are legally binding in your country if you use that certificate for signing PDF documents.

Comment: The host name in the link http://ocsp.mpb-ks.org:8080/crls/search.cgi?alias=email seems to indicate that the same host name is intended to be used for an OCSP service.

Comment: @mkl Yes, that's also what I thought, but it seems that an `email` is expected as `alias` and I didn't find an email in the certificate. That's why I looked for the documentation, but I didn't find any in a language I understand (maybe I overlooked).

Comment: Indeed, the certificate has an EKU extension indicating Email Protection only, see my appendix answer.

Answer (score 3):

*(As an appendix to [@Bruno's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36372535/1729265))*

@Bruno has observed

> I see that the Key Usage allows digital signing, but I don't know if your country allows to use that key for signing PDFs. I mean: technically it is possible, but I've read a notice that says "E-Mail Signature Certificate". I assume that the certificate is meant to sign e-mail and you are using it for a different purpose. Please check with your authorities if the signatures are legally binding in your country if you use that certificate for signing PDF documents.

Indeed, the user certificate has an `Extended Key Usage` extension:

[image: Certificate Viewer Details tab]

As you see it says *Email Protection* and nothing else.

This extension is specified in [RFC 5280 section 4.2.2.12](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.2.1.12) which in particular says:

> If the extension is present, then the certificate MUST only be used
> for one of the purposes indicated.  If multiple purposes are
> indicated the application need not recognize all purposes indicated,
> as long as the intended purpose is present.

In the case at hand there is only one purpose indicated, so the certificate MUST only be used for this purpose.

Thus, strictly speaking the certificate indeed is not meant for signing PDFs, merely for protecting e-mails.

### Adobe's point of view

If you wonder why Adobe Acrobat Reader does not complain about the use of this certificate, here some backgrounds:

Adobe have documented their acceptance of certificates by key usage and extended key usage since version 11.0.09 [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet-docs/acrobatetk/tools/DigSig/changes.html). In essence they allow any combination of these key usages

- *absent*
- `nonRepudiation`
- `signTransaction` (11.0.09 only)
- `digitalSignature` (11.0.10 and later)

and these extended key usages

- *absent*
- `emailProtection`
- `codeSigning`
- `anyExtendedKeyUsage`
- `1.2.840.113583.1.1.5` (Adobe Authentic Documents Trust)

They explain this as follows:

> RFC 5280, which started as RFC 2459 in 1999, did not include “Document Protection” as a potential EKU. Therefore, Adobe has always had to make certain assumptions regarding a Certificate Authority’s intention for the usage of an issued certificate.

> Recently, certificate usage has become more popular in enterprise settings where certificate-based authentication is used to access corporate networks in a variety of ways. Some of these certificates have relatively open KU and EKU configurations, and these have automatically been displayed back to the user within Adobe Reader and Acrobat as potential credentials for digitally signing PDF documents. After a re-evaluation of RFC 5280 and the actual industry practices for digital certificates, Adobe Acrobat and Reader 11.0.09 increase their conformance to RFC 5280 by no longer displaying all available certificates. In some cases, the changes will mean that certificates available for signing in earlier versions will not be displayed.

> According to RFC 5280, there are several ways to make sure your credential can be used for digital signing. First, from “4.2.1.3 Key Usage” in RFC 5280:

> > “The key usage extension defines the purpose (e.g., encipherment, signature, certificate signing) of the key contained in the certificate. The usage restriction might be employed when a key that could be used for more than one operation is to be restricted. For example, when an RSA key should be used only to verify signatures on objects other than public key certificates and CRLs, the digitalSignature and/or nonRepudiation bits would be asserted. Likewise, when an RSA key should be used only for key management, the keyEncipherment bit would be asserted.”

> And secondly, from “4.2.1.12 Extended Key Usage” in RFC 5280:

> > “This extension indicates one or more purposes for which the certified public key may be used, in addition to or in place of the basic purposes indicated in the key usage extension. In general, this extension will appear only in end entity certificates.”

> Further, when both KU and EKU are present, the RFC states:

> > “If a certificate contains both a key usage extension and an extended key usage extension, then both extensions MUST be processed independently and the certificate MUST only be used for a purpose consistent with both extensions. If there is no purpose consistent with both extensions, then the certificate MUST NOT be used for any purpose.”

In my opinion Adobe is too liberal here when accepting `emailProtection` and `codeSigning` - those usages are clearly different from document signing. Most likely they simply wanted to allow as many certificates in common use as possible to be usable for PDF signing while appearing to be RFC conform.